# Which statements about a linear transformation would be correct?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, linear-transformations

Let T be a linear transformation. If we have this then what statements would hold true?

1. T contains $\vec{0}$ (i.e $\vec{0} \in T$)
2. T is a 3 x 4 matrix
3. The columns of T are linearly independent
4. T($\vec{0}$) = $\vec{0}$
5. T is one-to-one
6. T is non-empty
7. The domain of T is $\mathbb{R}^4$

These sort of questions are given to us after each topic in algebra to understand if we know the concepts inside out.

My attempt would be that 3, 4 and 5 are true. Im unsure about others. 3, 4 and 5 I was able to find because of a theorem. I think 1 should be true, since $\vec{0}$ should be in the vector space. 7 can be true or can be false. The question doesn't specify so we assume it to be false. 2 and 6 i have no idea at all. Can T be empty? Because it would make no sense for it to be called a transformation if its empty.

Appreciate your time and effort

Comment: $T$ is a linear transformation, not a set, so it makes no sense to say that "some element belongs to $T$". For the others, I do not know the context of the question, but if it asserts that for \textit{any} given linear transformation $T$, which of the following ones are true, then it can certainly happen that $T$ may not be a specifc $3 \times 4$ matrix, or that their columns be linearly independent. If the context is "which of the following could be true if one knows that $T$ is a linear transformation?" then both 2 and 3 can certainly hold true. Similar reasonings exclude the others.

Comment: (continuation) For excluding I mean that some of them are particular examples of linear transformations, but some hold true for \textit{any} of them (for example, as you said, number 4).

Comment: Is it seriously a problem in a book/course? Points 1., 2., 3., 6. don't even make sense for a transformation (unless under certain identifications)..

Comment: @Berci unfortunately yes. Its a book written by our own professor and its the course text. Its pretty crappy considering he is all about rigour and precision but his questions are barely precise.